How to calculate the correct spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum
Given that AQE will automatically coalesce partitions at runtime, is there a recommended way to determine what spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum should be set to?
